# Create lookup table from libsvm training data in matlab

Tags: matlab, svm, libsvm

I'm using the svmtrain function of libsvm for a 3 Features and 2 class problem. For other reasons i want to build a lookup table based on the decision boundaries from the svmtrain results.

The LUT has 3 dimensions - one for each feature and each entry is either -1 or 1 (--> 2 class problem).

Does anybody have an idea how the training data could be used to build a lookup table?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you try to accomplish with this lookup table. SVM classifiers construct a separating **hyperplane**. A point's label is determined by the side of the hyperplane it resides on.

A hyperplane in n-dimensional space always separates it into two. You cannot determine which side a point is on by using less than n dimensions, in general. Your lookup table approach does not work.

Consider the following hyperplane in two dimensions: x1+x2=0 and you want to 'classify' a point based on one dimension, e.g. (x1val, ?) -> x1val + ? > 0. This is impossible.

Edit:

Still not sure what you are trying to do. If you simply want to tabulate your training set, just predict it with your model and structure the results the way you want them.

I can't see any reason to do this, though, so I guess I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: i guess my question was not clear enough: The points i want to classify are also 3 dimensional.
Referring to your 2d example: It should be possible possible to determine on which side of the hyperplane a point (x1val,x2val) is located.

Comment: That's how I understood it. But you cannot classify said points based on only 1 out of 3 dimensions. Is that what you want to do with the LUT?

Comment: as i just edited in my reply the classification is based on all 3 dimensions.